# Calculate time difference in a column and save it for many excel file with multiple spreadsheets, PYTHON

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, glob

I need to calculate the time difference for n excel files with multiple spreadsheets in my directory.
First, I split my dataframe into spreadsheets according to the date, then, I checked if two consecutive rows in the column `Door Name` are different or not and finally I calculated the time difference if the dataframe's length is even.

**step1:**

[image]

**step2:**

[image]

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import datetime
from tkinter import filedialog

pathEmp=Employees + "/*.xlsx" # Select directory using tkinter
for femp in glob.glob(pathEmp):
    print('******\n')
    name_file=os.path.split(femp)[-1]
    print('Employee ',name_file)

    xl = pd.ExcelFile(femp)
    print('Sheet name: ',xl.sheet_names)
    for sh in xl.sheet_names:
        df = xl.parse(sh)
        print('Processing: [{}] ...'.format(sh))
        print('length : ',len(df))
        df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
        df['value'] = (df[['Door Name']] != df[['Door Name']].shift()).any(axis=1)
        print('My df\n',df)
        for i in range (len(df)):
            if (len(df)) %2 == 0:
                if (df.value.nunique() == 1):
                    df['Working hours'] = df['Time'].iloc[1::2].to_numpy() - df['Time'].iloc[::2]
                    Total = df['Working hours'].sum()
                    Total = '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (Total.days*24 + Total.seconds // 3600, (Total.seconds % 3600) // 60, Total.seconds // 60)
        print('Working hours', Total)
```

**Expected output:**

[image]

**How can I save the column `Working hours` in each spreadsheet in every excel file in my directory?**

Comment: could you show `working hours` formula by specific date? is it sum of difference between IN/OUT? why `07:55:43` related to `2019-09-30 17:49:06`?

Comment: it's `df['Working hours'] = df['Time'].iloc[1::2].to_numpy() - df['Time'].iloc[::2]` 
and yes it's time difference between INs and OUTs

Comment: are there any others `DoorName`s?

Comment: just `RDC_IN-1` and `RDC_OUT-1`

Comment: Can you explain how to get `Working hours` from `original` file(step1)? I mean without loops etc? Is this just one value per column?

Comment: `working hours` = **sum** ( `Time` **where** `Door Name` = `RDC_IN`) -  **sum** ( `Time` **where** `Door Name` = `RDC_OUT`) or it's the **sum of the difference between each two consecutive rows**

Comment: can the original frame have duplicates by `Door Name` but with different `Time`? `('RDC_IN-1', 'RDC_IN-1', 'RDC_IN-1', 'RDC_OUT-1')` / `('2019-09-30 17:49:06', '2019-09-30 18:49:06', ...)` ? can there be a string without a pair in one date(only one `RDC_IN-1` or `RDC_OUT-1`)?

Comment: No, I sorted my table in order to only get the dataframe as shown in the images above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.

```
# your input
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DoorName': ('RDC_IN-1', 'RDC_OUT-1', 'RDC_IN-1', 'RDC_OUT-1', 'RDC_IN-1', 'RDC_OUT-1',
                 'RDC_IN-1', 'RDC_OUT-1', 'RDC_IN-1', 'RDC_OUT-1', 'RDC_IN-1'),
    'Time': (datetime(2019, 9, 30, 17, 49, 6), datetime(2019, 9, 30, 17, 45, 51),
             datetime(2019, 9, 30, 17, 45, 28), datetime(2019, 9, 30, 16, 37, 53),
             datetime(2019, 9, 30, 15, 59, 53), datetime(2019, 9, 30, 9, 15, 0),
             datetime(2019, 9, 27, 18, 25, 39), datetime(2019, 9, 27, 18, 27, 9),
             datetime(2019, 9, 27, 12, 10, 33),
             datetime(2019, 9, 27, 8, 42, 50), datetime(2019, 9, 27, 18, 24, 34)),
})

df['name'] = 'Arya Stark'
# generate date column from Time column
df['date'] = df['Time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# open file for writing
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    # for each unique date
    for u_date in df['date'].unique():  # type: str
        # sub DataFrame from main DataFrame by date
        df_by_date = df[df['date'] == u_date]
        # date column is no longer needed
        df_by_date = df_by_date.drop(columns=['date'])
        # DoorName Cumulative sum + group by name (Arya Stark)
        s = df_by_date['DoorName'].eq('RDC_IN-1').iloc[::].cumsum()
        con = df_by_date.name.groupby(s).transform('nunique') == 1
        # diff in seconds between RDC_IN and RDC_OUT for each couple
        sec_df = df_by_date[con].groupby(s).agg({
            'Time': lambda x: (x.iloc[0] - x.iloc[-1]).seconds
        })

        df_by_date = df_by_date.reset_index()
        df_by_date = df_by_date.drop(columns=['index'])
        df_by_date['WorkingHours'] = ''
        # sum all seconds and convert to timedelta
        working_hours = str(timedelta(seconds=int(sec_df['Time'].sum())))
        # insert only in first row of sheet(as in your example)
        df_by_date['WorkingHours'].loc[0] = working_hours
        # append sheet by unique date
        df_by_date.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=u_date, index=False)
```

You'll see expected file. See comments - I'm sure you can customize it if you need some changes. Hope this helps.